# Not able to access data inside a PHP array of object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I´m trying to access data inside a object create after a response(from a dafiti server) with no succsess.

Bellow my code:

```
***$response = Endpoints::order()->getOrder($orderId)->call($client);


$o = $response->getBody();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($o);
echo "</pre>";
foreach($o as $value => $obj){
   
$orderId = $obj->Order->OrderID;// tried this way(not working)

$CustomerFirstName = $obj['Order']['CustomerFirstName'];// tried this way(not working)

}******
```

Bellow the var_dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["Orders"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Order"]=>
    array(23) {
      ["OrderId"]=>
      string(7) "8266761"
      ["CustomerFirstName"]=>
      string(6) "sheila"
      ["CustomerLastName"]=>
      string(14) "rocha domingos"
      ["OrderNumber"]=>
      string(10) "4510948375"
      ["PaymentMethod"]=>
      string(22) "braspag_cc_master_card"
      ["Currency"]=>
      string(3) "BRL"
```

... to be continue.

How can I access the values inside this array?

Comment: The first way can't work because you have an array, not an object. The second one should work; I cannot reproduce the problem using your code. Can you specify what you expect your code to do? Maybe it's a problem with how you're using it further in the script.

Comment: Yes, i´m trying to, for example, save  the "CustomerFirstName" value to a specific variable. The second code did not work too. Thanks

Comment: For future reference: "does/did not work" is too vague. You should always specify in what way your code differs from your expectation (throws errors/warnings/notices, gets wrong values...).

Comment: El_vanja Sorry for my mistake and só thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains an array of orders inside of the 'Orders' field of the $o array. So you need to iterate over $o['Orders']. Then you'll be able to access your order details.

```
<?php

$o = [
    'Orders' => [
        'Order' => [
            'OrderId'           => '8266761',
            'CustomerFirstName' => 'sheila',
            'CustomerLastName'  => 'rocha domingos',
            'OrderNumber'       => '4510948375',
            'PaymentMethod'     => 'braspag_cc_master_card',
            'Currency'          => 'BRL'
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($o['Orders'] as $order) {
    $orderId           = $order['OrderId'];
    $CustomerFirstName = $order['CustomerFirstName'];

    var_dump($orderId); // 8266761
    var_dump($CustomerFirstName); // sheila
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail Prosalov, solved my problem!

Comment: OP's access `$obj['Order']['CustomerFirstName']` should still work with an array formed like this. I literally do not understand the issue here or how this solves it. [See fiddle](https://3v4l.org/esaai).